# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. Unsure how to resolve this error

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

[image]

I am trying to POST the data from a form using TextFormFields to an API and am facing this error which states that setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build and is marking the Form as the root of the error and I am unable to understand how to resolve it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
class EnquiryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const EnquiryScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EnquiryScreen> createState() => _EnquiryScreenState();
}

class _EnquiryScreenState extends State<EnquiryScreen> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final Map<String, String> _enqData = {
    "name": "",
    "email": "",
    "contactNo": "",
    "message": "",
    "enquiryFor": "",
    "category": "",
  };

  void getName(String name) => _enqData['name'] = name;
  void getEmail(String email) => _enqData['email'] = email;
  void getNumber(String phNumber) => _enqData['contactNo'] = phNumber;
  void getMessage(String msg) => _enqData['message'] = msg;
  void getFor(String enqFor) => _enqData['enquiryFor'] = enqFor;
  void getCategory(String catgy) => _enqData['category'] = catgy;

  void enqSubmit(BuildContext context) {
    isLoading = true;
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      isLoading = false;
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    enquiry(context);
    isLoading = false;
  }

  Future<void> enquiry(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await Provider.of<EnquiryData>(context, listen: false)
          .submitEnquiryForm(_enqData);
    } on HttpException catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.message);
    } catch (e) {
      log("Error login auth widget " + e.toString());
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error : " + e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(appBarTitle: 'Enquiry'),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  const Text(
                    'Name',
                    style: openSans16DarkBold,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  EnquiryName(getValue: getName),
                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                  const Text(
                    'Email',
                    style: openSans16DarkBold,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  EnquiryEmail(getValue: getEmail),
                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                  const Text(
                    'Contact Number',
                    style: openSans16DarkBold,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  EnquiryContact(getValue: getNumber),
                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                  const Text(
                    'Message',
                    style: openSans16DarkBold,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  EnquiryMessage(getValue: getMessage),
                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                  const Text(
                    'Enquiry for',
                    style: openSans16DarkBold,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  EnquiryFor(getValue: getFor),
                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                  const Text(
                    'Category',
                    style: openSans16DarkBold,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 4),
                  EnquiryCategory(getValue: getCategory),
                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                  Center(
                    child: EnquirySubmit(
                      submit: enqSubmit,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is in EnquirySubmit.  Can you post that class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setState in your getter methods.